# replenishing pools in the html table

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have tables to do in html,

```
<thead>
...
</thead>
<tbody>

// tbody has 30 rows for 15 columns.
</tbody>
```

in several columns I have to insert the field

```
<input type = "time" name = "1st-row/1st-column">
<input type = "time" name = "2nd-row/1st-column">
<input type = "time" name = "3rd-row/1st-column">
<input type = "time" name = "30th-row/1st-column">
```

- the same 2nd-column / 3rd-column / 5th-column + ... + 10th column

Do I have to insert fields there directly via html, is it possible to do it faster and more clearly? If this is how to do it?

Comment: Do you want to do this with Javascript or Razor?

Comment: @panoskarajohn 
file extension .cshtml (razor), I would prefer a razor

Comment: Well I see already people have answered you. Elaborate on how you want the behavior to be if you want sth different than what they already have provided..

Answer (score 1):

```
 <table>
        <thead>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for(int i=0;i<30;i++) 
                {
                  <tr>
                    @for(int y=0;y<15;y++)
                    {
                     <td>columns...</td>
                    }
                 </tr>
               }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a loop that creates elements with document.createElement() and add them with element.appendChild()